# How would you evaluate the following expression? It seems very difficult to simplify the trig.

Tags: calculus, integration, math-software

[image]

I have tried to many different ways and I also end up with a tan inside an arctan which I do not know how to simplify. Please suggest how I can solve this. Am I missing something simple or is it quite tricky and need some sort of manipulation that I am missing.

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: Maple gets the answer $2$.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @Robert Israel, see [my comments here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/non-experts-closing-questions/33801#comment155268_33801).

Comment: Just posted again on MSE. This time with a source cited https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249542/evaluate-the-expression-sqrt-sqrt-frac13a5-a4-8a3-8a2-32a ...AND it was immediately deleted, but the source was https://mobile.twitter.com/SrinivasR1729/status/1437025537856180224?s=20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By symmetry we can reduce the interval to $[0,\frac{\pi}4]$, the coefficient before the integral sign becomes $8$.

$$I=\frac 8{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\dfrac{\cos(4x)^2+1}{a\cos(2x)^2+1}dx$$

Then by substitution $u=2x$:

$$I=\frac 4{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\dfrac{\cos(2u)^2+1}{a\cos(u)^2+1}du$$

The reason behind reducing the interval is to be able to have a bijective change $t=\tan(u)$:

We expand $\cos(2u)$ and replace $\cos(u)^2$ by $\frac 1{1+t^2}$:

$$I=\frac 8{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{t^4+1}{(t^2+a+1)(t^2+1)^2}du$$

The next part is partial fraction decomposition and integration in arctan, it is not difficult but tedious, so I skip it and jump to the result:

$$\dfrac {\tfrac{a^2+2a+2}{a^2}}{t^2+a+1}-\dfrac {\frac{2a+2}{a^2}}{t^2+1}+\dfrac {\frac 2a}{(t^2+1)^2}$$

$$I=4\times\frac{(a^2+2a+2)-\sqrt{1+a}(a+2)}{a^2\sqrt{1+a}}$$

We now have to solve $I=a$ :

$4(a^2+2a+2)-4\sqrt{1+a}(a+2)=a^3\sqrt{1+a}\iff 4(a^2+2a+2)=\sqrt{1+a}(a^3+4a+8)$

We square both sides and simplify to:

$$a^7+a^6+8a^5+8a^4-32a^3-48a^2=0$$

And since $a\neq 0$ we are glad to arrive to the desired expression:

> $$a^5+a^4+8a^3+8a^2-32a=48$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $ a = b^2$ for convenience and suppose,

$$
\begin{align} 
y  & = \frac{\cos^24x+1}{a\cos^22x+1}\\
&= \frac{(2\cos^2{2x}-1)^2+1}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
&= \frac{4\cos^4{2x}-4\cos^2{2x}+2}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
&=\frac{4\cos^4{2x}}{b^2\cos^22x+1}
-\frac{4\cos^2{2x}}{b^2\cos^22x+1}
+\frac{2}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
&=A-B+C
\end{align}
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{4\cos^4{2x}}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
&=\frac{4}{b^4} \left( \frac{b^4\cos^4{2x}}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{4}{b^4} \left( \frac{b^4\cos^4{2x}-1+1}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{4}{b^4} \left( \frac{((b\cos2x)^2+1)((b\cos2x)^2-1)}{b^2\cos^22x+1} +\frac{1}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{4}{b^4} \left( (b\cos{2x})^2-1 +\frac{1}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{4}{b^2}\cos^2{2x}+\frac{4}{b^4} \left( \frac{1}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)-\frac{4}{b^4}\\
\text{or} \ A&=\frac{4}{a}\cos^2{2x}+\frac{4}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{a\cos^22x+1} \right)-\frac{4}{a^2} \qquad(1)
\end{align}
$$

Simplifying B,
$$
\begin{align}
B &= \frac{4\cos^2{2x}}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
&= \frac{4}{b^2} \left( \frac{(b\cos{2x})^2}{b^2\cos^22x+1} \right)\\
&= \frac{4}{b^2} \left( \frac{(b\cos{2x})^2+1-1}{(b\cos{2x})^2+1}
 \right)\\
&= \frac{4}{b^2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{(b\cos{2x})^2+1}
 \right)\\
&= \frac{4}{b^2} -\frac{4}{b^2}\left(\frac{1}{b^2\cos^2{2x}+1} \right)\\
\text{or} \ B &= \frac{4}{a} -\frac{4}{a}\left(\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1} \right) \qquad(2)\\
\end{align}
$$

Now,

$$
\begin{align}
A-B+C &= \frac{4}{a}\cos^2{2x}+\frac{4}{a^2} \left( \frac{1}{a\cos^22x+1} \right)-\frac{4}{a^2}
-\frac{4}{a} +\frac{4}{a}\left(\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1} \right)
+\frac{2}{b^2\cos^22x+1}\\
\text{or}\ y&= \frac{4}{a}\cos^2{2x} + \left( \frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{4}{a} +2 \right)\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1}
-\left( \frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{4}{a} \right) \qquad(3)\\
\end{align}
$$
Now,
$$
\int^\pi_{-\pi}\cos^2{2x}\,dx = {\pi} \qquad(4)
$$
and,
$$\begin{align}
\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1}\,dx &= 8\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1}\,dx \\
&= 8\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\frac{\sec^2{2x}}{a+\sec^2{2x}}\,dx\\
&= 8\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\frac{\sec^2{2x}}{a+1+\tan^2{2x}}\,dx\\
&= 4\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} {\left[\tan^-1{\left(\frac{\tan{2x}}{\sqrt{a+1}} \right)}\right]}_{0}^{\pi/4}\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a+1}} \qquad(5)
\end{align}
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{\cos^2(4x) +1}{a\cos^2(2x)+1}\,dx &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}y\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \left({\frac{4}{a}{\pi} + 
\left(\frac{4}{a^2} +\frac{4}{a}+2 \right)\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a+1}}
 -2{\pi}\left( \frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{4}{a} \right)} \right)\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, as per the problem statement,
$$
{\frac{4}{a} + 
\left(\frac{4}{a^2} +\frac{4}{a}+2 \right)\frac{2}{\sqrt{a+1}}
 -2\left( \frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{4}{a} \right)} =a
$$
A multiplication of ${a^2}{\sqrt{a+1}} $ on both sides and then squaring both side will yield
$$
\begin{align}
& a^7 +a^6+8a^5+8a^4-32a^3-48a^2=0\\
& \Rightarrow a^5+a^4+8a^3+8a^2-32a =48\\
& \Rightarrow \sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(a^5+a^4+8a^3+8a^2-32a)}}
\Rightarrow \sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{48}{3}}} = 2.
\end{align}
$$

---

---